# Fixity of infix value constructors

Tags: haskell

Let:

```
data Some a b = Some a b deriving (Show)
```

Then (in ghci):

```
> Some (id 1) (id 2)
Some 1 2
```

But (not surprisingly):

```
> Some id 1 id 2
Couldn't match expected type ‘(a1 -> a1) -> Integer -> t’ ...
```

However:

```
> id 1 `Some` id 2
Some 1 2
```

Why is that? Does fixity of infix value constructors defaults to the lowest?

Comment: Operators have lower precedence than function application. Compare `Some` with `+`, what do you expect for `id 1 + id 2`.

Comment: I'd say fixity is immaterial here, since application has higher precedence w.r.t. any infix operation.

Comment: So normally value constructor is a function but when I'm using backticks constructor is an operator?

Comment: @Siegmeyer: whether it is a constructor is irrelevant here. It is a function. If you put a function between backquotes, it acts like an operator (given it is of the type `a -> b -> c`. If you write ```<exp1> `f` <exp2>```, it is equivalent to `f (<exp1>) (<exp2>)`.

Comment: Ok, gotcha, that clears it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor is a function as well: we can use a constructor `C` as a function that takes the parameters the constructor is going to hold as arguments, and then constructs a new instance of the type. So in your example, Haskell syntactically sees `Some` like it sees any function.

If you write a function between backquotes (`` ` ``), then it acts like an *operator*, like it is written in [*Section 3 of the Haskell '98 report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html):

> An operator is either an operator symbol, such as `+` or `$$`, or is an **ordinary identifier enclosed in grave accents** (backquotes), such as `` `op` ``. For example, instead of writing the prefix application `op x y`, one can write the infix application `` x `op` y ``. **If no fixity declaration is given for `` `op` `` then it defaults to highest precedence and left associativity**.

The section also describes that function application has priority over operators. We see that an expression `exp` can be a `fexp` (an function application expression). The arguments of such function application are `aexp`s. An `aexp` *can* contain an operator (through `exp`), but only in case it is between brackets (`()`), square brackets (`[]`, when we construct a list), etc. But not without a specification of priority. If we write: `f a b + g x a`, it is thus interpreted as `(f a b) + (g x y)`, *not* as <s>`f a (b+g) x y`</s>.

Now the only question that is still open is what happens in case the expression contains other operators. In Haskell we assign precedence (and associativty) to operators. This is described in [*Section 4 of the Haskell '98 report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html). All operators are assigned a precedence between `0` and `9`. The `*` operator has for instance higher precedence than `+`, and that means that `2 + 3 * 2` is interpreted as `2 + (3 * 2)`, and not as <s>`(2 + 3) * 2`</s>. As is described in the quoted section, if you do *not* specify the precedence, then it is the highest. So `1 + id 2`Some`id 3 * 5` is interpreted as `` 1 + (((id 2) `Some` (id 3)) * 5) `` (but this makes no sense here, since we can not multiply a `Some` object with `5`.

So your expression:

```
id 1 `Some` id 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
Some (id 1) (id 2)
```